# How to empty and refill jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable on my page. This datatable is gonna show data based on a request made to my api

The HTML that I have is like the following:

```
<table id="details" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped nowrap hidden display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Patient Full Name</th>
            <th class="hidden">LF</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Patient Full Name</th>
            <th class="hidden">LF</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="dummytr2"><td style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;" colspan="7"><p><em>No Data Available</em></p></td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

The first `<th>` is gonna be used to collapse the tr and get the facility (the third `<th>` or the hidden one) of this patient.

I have a dummy `<tr>` in the table because I don't want to initialize the datatable at the beginning so I don't get the error message that tells me that I can't initialize my datatable twice.

The request to my api is gonna be triggered through a bunch of buttons like the following:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://" + window.myLocalVar + "/api/metrics/GetDetails?metricName=" + metric,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (requests) {

                if (requests.length > 0) {
                    $("#dummytr2").remove();
                    for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
                        var patient_name = requests[i].PatientFullName;
                        var lab_facility = requests[i].LabFacility;

                        tr = '<tr>\
                                    <td class=" details-control"></td>\
                                    <td>' + patient_name + '</td>\                                 
                                    <td class="hidden">' + lab_facility + '</td>\
                                </tr>';

                                $("#details > tbody").append(tr);



                                //click event for each tr
                                $('#details tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                                    var row = table.row(tr);

                                    if (row.child.isShown()) {
                                        // This row is already open - close it
                                        row.child.hide();
                                        tr.removeClass('shown');
                                    } else {
                                        // Open this row
                                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                                        tr.addClass('shown');
                                    }
                                });
                        }  
                    }
                // NOT SURE WHY IT IS NOT WORKING    
                $('#details').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                var table = $('#details').DataTable({
                    "scrollX": true,
                    stateSave: true,
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "className": 'details-control',
                            "orderable": false,
                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent": ''
                        },
                        { "data": "PatientFullName" },
                        { "data": "LabFacility" }
                        ],
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        });
    });

function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    var lf = d.LabFacility;
    if (lf == "") {
        lf = "No Lab Facility"
    }
    // wrapping text is not working???
    return '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table display" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
         '<tr>' +
            '<td>Lab Facility:</td>' +
            '<td>' + lf + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
    '</table></div>';
}
```

This ajax request is gonna get called each time a button is clicked. This means the content of my datatable is going to change each time a button was clicked. I tried to clear and refill it did not work.. I tried to destroy it .. it did not work.. each time I destroy my datatable and execute the script it won't change the content of the table.

I am not sure what's wrong with my code. My code works only for the first time.. the second time you click a button, it won't update my datatable.

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting up the dataTable outside of your ajax request, and each time you call your ajax request to get new data, just empty the datatable object, add the new rows, and then re-draw, instead of attempt to initialize the dataTable each time an ajax request is made. Do the same with your click event handlers, set those up outside of the ajax request success method.

Comment: Hi, you can use the **ajax option** from [Datatable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax). And every time you want to refresh you can use `table.api().ajax.reload();`

Comment: @dnviveros, I tried to use $('#details').dataTable().api().ajax.reload(); instead of $('#details').dataTable().fnDestroy(); but it said invalid json response. Could you please provide the right place to add that command

Comment: @Woodrow I tried that method and it did not work

Comment: sorry, I meant, that you have to stop using the "normal ajax" and use only the dataTable ajax for example: `$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.search = $('#search').val();
    }
  }
} );`

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- empty the table with `empty()`
- remove `$('#details').dataTable().fnDestroy();`
- add `destroy: true` option

For example:

```js
if (requests.length > 0) {

   // Empty table        
   $('#details').empty(); 

   // ... skipped ... 

   var table = $('#details').DataTable({
      destroy: true,
      // ... skipped ...
   });

   // ... skipped ... 
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution .. it is not working .. it is basically removing all the table with its content. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see sample of what I was saying in comments above:

```js
var dataTable_ = null;
var init_ = false;

var initDataTable = function() {

  dataTable_ = $('#table').DataTable({
    preDrawCallback: function(settings) {

    },
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      if (init_ === false) {
        init_ = true;
      }
    },
    searching: true,
    data: [],
    fnCreatedRow: function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {

    },
    scrollY: true,
    scrollX: true,
    responsive: false,
    serverSide: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    processing: false,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    fixedColumns: false,
    info: false,
    select: {
      info: false,
      items: 'rows'
    },
    dom: '<"toolbar">Bfrtip',
    orderMulti: false,
    stripeClasses: ['dt-stripe-1', 'dt-stripe-2'],
    columns: [{
        name: 'test1',
        data: 'test1',
        title: 'Test1',
        type: 'string',
        orderable: true
      },
      {
        name: 'test2',
        data: 'test2',
        title: 'Test2',
        type: 'string',
        orderable: true
      },
    ]
  });

};

var ajaxFunction = function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7ed89",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (init_ === false) {
        initDataTable();
      }
      if (typeof dataTable_ == 'object') {
        dataTable_.rows().remove().draw();
        dataTable_.rows.add(data);
        dataTable_.draw();
      }
      //console.log(data);
    }
  });

};


$('#button').click(function() {
  ajaxFunction();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="cell-border hover call-list">
</table>
<button id="button">Click To Load Data</button>
```

Comment: I am trying to test the your code .. however, I am having difficulties trying to integrate your code with mine